# Lazy loading req.user, with express and passport?

Tags: node.js, express

We are using express and for certain operations want to check the details of the logged in user. We would rather avoid a DB hit every time for filling in `req.user`, it would be good to only load the data if it is read. API endpoints are protected by JWT, which is validated at each access.

Is there a way of going about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple solutions:

1. You can put these details directly into JWT, therefore having all this information avialable without calling db. It is not viable if there is some secrets/passwords or if the data you need can change often (as it will remain old in JWT until refresh).
2. The easiest way is just to use method. Instead of `req.user` call `req.getUser()` or have function `getUser(req)`. Inside that function, you can write all your business logic, which would be like - check if user is already stored in `req._user`. If so, return it. If not, load it from db, store it to `req._user` and return it.
3. Yes, there is a way to handle "getting" of properties directly from `req.user`, altough I would avoid that and use one of the previous options if possible. If you have some old code with old node.js, you can use this deprecated method [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/**defineGetter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__defineGetter__) if you are using modern node.js, then this is the way now https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get